# Virtualenv not working after Python upgrade. What to do?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, homebrew

I built a small app in python and everything was running smoothly. Afterwards, I decided to upgrade python to 2.7.5 with homebrew. When I went back to start a new project, I was no longer able to create the virtual environment. This is the ERROR I'm getting:

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages club_envNew python executable in club_env/bin/python
ERROR: The executable club_env/bin/python is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is u'/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7' (should be u'/Users/myusername/Code/python/club/club_env')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

Could someone please explain

1. What is happening here, so that I understand the problem, and
2. How I can fix this, and
3. If there was something I should have done differently from the beginning?

Comment: you making virtualenv from virtualenv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reinstall `` `virtualenv `` in the new `Python 2.7.5` default environment and then you will be able to create new virtual environments again.

Comment: Do I need to --clear my current virtualenv install first? When I go to do a reinstall it just tells me "Requirement is already satisfied"

Comment: Also, if that is the case, how can I find out where (the path) I need to do the -clear?

Comment: So I ran --help on virtualenv and it says this, "The Python interpreter to use, e.g., --python=python2.5 will use the python2.5 interpreter to create the new environment.  The default is the interpreter that virtualenv was installed with (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python)". Doesn't this mean it is already using the interpreter from 2.7?

Comment: @Jordy When I install `virtualenv` I normally use the version of Python that I want in the virtual environment. That way there is no doubt about which Python will be used in the new environment.

Answer (score 1):

I notice that you don't mention which python you upgraded from but my best guess of your problem:

1. You are telling virtualenv that the actuall python executable is in club_env/build/python - Is it?
2. Tell virtualenv where python really is or just accept the defaul behavour and see what that gets you.
3. A couple of answers spring to mind but they would get me slapped.